# iPad 2 cannot connect to a Microsoft Exchange server with Outlook Web Access (OWA)

Tags: email, ipad, exchange-activesync

I just bought an iPad 2 and wish to link to the Microsoft Exchange email server Outlook Web Access connection. Sadly even though all details are correct it still says that the details are unable to be verified and obviously can not load emails.

For the record i can successfully connect via OWA connection on browser.

Also I have been able to load calendar.
Also the Signature also seems to have been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

iOS does not use Outlook Web Access for Exchange support, it uses ActiveSync. Summarized setup instructions from this [Apple support article titled iOS: Setting up Exchange ActiveSync](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2480):

1. Tap **Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Add Account > Microsoft Exchange**
2. Enter the information in the fields shown, then hit **Next**
3. Your iOS device will now try to locate your Exchange server. If necessary, you will need to enter your front-end Exchange server's complete address in the **Server** field.
4. Choose which content you would like to synchronize: Mail, Contacts, and Calendars. Tap **Save** when finished.

(See the linked support article for the screenshots provided by Apple.)

Answer (score 0):

You should have the Microsoft Exchange Server administrator to enable *Autodiscover* in Outlook Web Access for the time it takes you to first authenticate your Mail program on your iPad. Afterwards the administrator can disable Auto-Discovery if it is deemed undesirable.

Apple's documentation for connecting to a Macintosh says the following. I'm assuming the same will apply to configuring the Mail app on an iPad.

> Connecting to an Exchange Server
>
> To connect a Mac to an Exchange server, you’ll need the following
>   pieces of information from the server administrator:
>
> - The fully qualified domain name for the organization’s Client
>     Access    Server (CAS), typically expressed in the format:
>     exchange01.example.com.
> - The Exchange user name, which is generated by the administrator for
>     each individual user.
> - The Exchange password, which is also generated for each user. Once 
>     you have the required information, you can either manually configure
>     your Mac to use Exchange, or configure the Mac using the Exchange
>     Autodiscover service, if it’s enabled.
>
> Connect to an Exchange server with Autodiscover enabled:
>
> The easiest way to set up Mail, Address Book, and iCal to access
>   Exchange is the Exchange Autodiscover service. If this feature is
>   enabled on the Exchange Server, simply open the Add Account pane in
>   Mail on your Mac and enter your Exchange email address and password.
>
> Mail uses the Autodiscover service in Exchange to obtain the relevant
>   information and you can start using Exchange services immediately.